# Is amazon simpleDB suitable service for checking an android app's trial status?

Tags: android, database, cloud, amazon-simpledb, trialware

I have an android application and it has a trial version. I want to store users' imei numbers and installation dates on serverside and than check everytime when user uses this app to know if trial version is expired. Since i am not experienced on server side programming i was hoping this kind of cloud service would solve my problem. Before i jump into it i would like to be sure if simpleDB is suitable service for me and if not could you suggest another solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is securely storing the access credentials. To access the SimpleDB service without an intermediate server, you'll need to store the access credentials in your Android app. These are accessible with very little skill (text editor?) and could potentially allow unauthorised access to you Amazon Web Services account.

For a while there have been some options for creating extra credentials with varying access levels (eg. read-only) but I've yet to explore this myself.

**UPDATE**

Amazon have updated their Android libraries with [improved credential management](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/09/updated-mobile-sdks-for-aws-improved-credential-management.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29). This answer for [anonymous, read-only access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988367/anonymous-read-with-amazon-simpledb) describes in more detail how to use AWS Identity & Access Management.